# Angular get Membervalue of Object

Tags: angular, typescript

Did anyone know how to get a value of an object in Angular but with a variable as memberidentifier...

something like:

--> my Angular class object:

```
Object1 {
name: foo
property2: bar
}
```

--> my function:

```
myFunction(memberName: string) 
{ 
   return Object1.membername 
}
```

--> when executing:
myFunction("name") returns "foo"

is that possible?

Add:

this is the object class:

```
 import { headerStateColor } from "../header/headerDeviceStateColor.model";
 import { betterNameForDeviceState } from "./deviceStateHelper";

export class deviceModel {
    public deviceState: string;
    public device_id: string;
    public mac_address: string;
    public device_hostname: string;
    public device_name: string;
    public device_update_token: string;
    public used_chip: string;
    public device_firmware_type: string;
    public device_firmware_version: string;
    public device_firmware_version_installed: string;
    public device_fs_version: string;
    public device_fs_version_installed: string;
    public last_updated: any;
    public last_update_check: any;
    public device_is_locked: string;
    public device_to_destroy: string;
    public device_is_destroyed: string;
    public force_update: string;
    public ip_address: string;
    public ip_netmask: string;
    public ip_gateway: string;
    public dns_server: string;
    public ssid: string;
    public uptime: any;

    public stateColorPicker: headerStateColor = new headerStateColor();
    public deviceStateColorCode: string;
    public backgroundColor: string;
    public betterStatename: string;

    constructor(deviceState: string, device_id: string, mac_address: string, device_hostname: string, device_name: string, device_update_token: string,
        used_chip: string, device_firmware_type: string, device_firmware_version: string, device_firmware_version_installed: string,
        device_fs_version: string, device_fs_version_installed: string, last_updated: string, last_update_check: string,
        device_state: string, device_is_locked: string, device_to_destroy: string, device_is_destroyed: string,
        force_update: string, ip_address: string, ip_netmask: string, ip_gateway: string, dns_server: string,
        ssid: string, uptime: string, backgroundcolor: string = "#FFFFFF")
    {
        this.deviceState = deviceState;
        this.device_id = device_id;
        this.mac_address = mac_address;
        this.device_hostname = device_hostname;
        this.device_name = device_name;
        this.device_update_token = device_update_token;
        this.used_chip = used_chip;
        this.device_firmware_type = device_firmware_type;
        this.device_firmware_version = device_firmware_version;
        this.device_firmware_version_installed = device_firmware_version_installed;
        this.device_fs_version = device_fs_version;
        this.device_fs_version_installed = device_fs_version_installed;
        this.last_updated = last_updated;
        this.last_update_check = last_update_check;
        this.deviceState = device_state;
        this.device_is_locked = device_is_locked;
        this.device_to_destroy = device_to_destroy;
        this.device_is_destroyed = device_is_destroyed;
        this.force_update = force_update;
        this.ip_address = ip_address;
        this.ip_netmask = ip_netmask;
        this.ip_gateway = ip_gateway;
        this.dns_server = dns_server;
        this.ssid = ssid;
        this.uptime = uptime;
        this.deviceStateColorCode = this.stateColorPicker.getColorCodeOfState(deviceState);
        this.backgroundColor = this.stateColorPicker.getColorCodeBg(deviceState);

        this.betterStatename = betterNameForDeviceState(this.deviceState);
    };
}
```

This is the class i need to use the "dynamic member"

```
export class DeviceDetailsComponent implements OnInit {


  public betterName = betterNameForDeviceState;
  deviceDetails: deviceModel[] = [];
  deviceDetailModel: deviceModel = this.deviceDetails[0];
  changedDeviceDetailModel: deviceModel = this.deviceDetails[0];

  [...]
  
  //This class i want to use field as member identifier (this doesn't work  inputProcessing(field: string) {
     if(this.deviceDetailModel != NULL)
     {
       this.deviceDetailModel[field]
     }
   }

   //This work in general but i need test as dynamic variable
   inputProcessing(field: string) {
     if(this.deviceDetailModel != NULL)
     {
       const test = "device_name"
       this.deviceDetailModel[test]
     }
   }
```

This error is shown if I want to use the variable as identifier

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'deviceModel'.
 No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'deviceModel'.ts(7053)
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects contains a detailed explanation of how to work with objects, including "You can also access properties by using a string value that is stored in a variable".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the bracket syntax:

```
myFunction(memberName: string) 
{ 
   return Object1[memberName]
}


inputProcessing(field: string) {
     if(this.deviceDetailModel != NULL)
     {
       (this.deviceDetailModel as any)[field]
     }
   }
```

To answer your question, we need to understand one thing, in TypeScript when we use bracket syntax to access any object properties, the object must support indexable type. In your example, you are trying to access :

```
this.deviceDetailModel[field]
```

Point to note is deviceDetailModel is of type `deviceModel` which has below indexed keys of the same type:

```
        'deviceState'
        'device_id'
        'mac_address'
         ... and so on
```

Now since you are trying to access:

```
this.deviceDetailModel[field]
```

and field is of type string and not of any indexed type as we see above, we see that error:

When you access it directly, using 'deviceState', it will work as you are using one the indexed keys;

```
this.deviceDetailModel['deviceState']
```

So to get rid of this indexed key issue, either we can explicitly mark `deviceDetailModel` as any type, as I did in my answer, or we assign an indexable type to `deviceDetailModel`.

Let's understand this with a simple example, Below is a simple class type:

```
 class Person {
    name: string;
    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Now if we have an object of type Person:

```
const person1: Person = { name : 'Ritesh' };
```

and when we access name of person1 using dot notation:

```
console.log(person1.name) // This will work
```

And, if you try to access the name using bracket syntax:

```
console.log(person1['name']) // it will work too as we are passing an name which is an indexed key
```

And if we do this:

```
const n = 'name';
console.log(person1[n]) // This will still work as n is of type 'name;
```

But when we do this, assigning an explicit type to n (string):

```
const n: string = 'name';
console.log(person1[n])
```

it will throw the error

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Person'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Person'.
```

So if want to now correct the above issue, we can either use any:

```
const n: string = 'name';
console.log((person1 as any)[n])
```

Or

Make Person an indexable type from class:

```
 interface Person {
   {[key: string] : string
 }
```

Here we are saying Person type has keys of type string and values of type string as well.

Check this playground for better understanding :)
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQYwNghgzlwAoFMBOUD2A7YBvAsAKGEOHQgFsEAuYKAFyQEt0BzAbnyNA1qQFcQbUSABQlyVboyYBKbOw5EaAC3pQAdKITAAvMTII2BIgF98JvPjAIawAA7I0mHVl3lgVAOQAlejQRRF7kYG+BCWSDRCdigY6npSLIQA9InAAG6h9AAmIWERUQ4A2u4a7gC68cDJwABqoWBZ+CBc1gBm2sDFeu4JVRrAKtR0ggiZ-ZhtEOijSgiYPFAjOch59hgFLeWVKRJgYGkZ2eZ4VQBCPNZKAwDu9LvEqNZXggDWwJPTikioV8DIX0iNZrAJjiOiSdqdcjdfAwvChZaRVboApMcrBY4pK6aECTe4-eaaSYAT3YjF8SBaEBAmkQ0UwuEMwAKzwQRNBDGYpTcgw5THYZlhsKAA

Comment: Thanks for your help but this is not wworking for me... I already found this Bracket type Syntax but if i want to use it with a function variable it doesn't work (Error: 
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'deviceModel'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'deviceModel'.ts(7053)) 

If I use a const var like 
const testName = "device_name"; 
this.deviceDetailModel[testName]; 

this works fine but if I use a var like in your example this doesn't work...

Comment: what is the value of field that you get?

Comment: field is a string with a dynamic name from the deviceModel class like "mac_address" - field is the parameter of function inputProcessing (added above in my question)

Comment: many thanks for your help. now it's working ^^ - But one last question: Why is this necessary (--> (this.deviceDetailModel as any)[field]   <--) - for me it is the same like this.deviceDetailModel[field] except the conversion to "any" type... Can you explain this :) - may thanks ^^